# Syntax for multiline variables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am new to the Razor engine.  What I am trying to accomplish is to set a local variable containing css classes.  I would prefer to have this in a more readable format should anyone need to modify this later on.

What is the correct syntax to accomplish this?
(I first tried myCSS = "...", then I attempted to use @Html.Raw method)

The only way I can get it to work is to keep everything on one line.

Currently I have:

```
@{ var myCSS = @Html.Raw("<style>table {border-collapse: collapse; } ...etc</style>"); }
```

I would like something more readable. Such as:

```
@{ var myCss = @Html.Raw("
<style>
   table {border-collapse: collapse; } 
   etc....
</style>
"); }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to use `Html.Raw` because you are defining a C# variable. `Html.Raw` should be used in the place, where you need to render your CSS.

To preserve the formating you can use the '[verbatim string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)'. It suppress special characters (such as '\' or 'new line') until the next double-quote is encountered.

```
@{
    var myCss = @"
        <style>
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }

            etc....
        </style>";
}

@Html.Raw(myCss)
```

Another question is, why you need CSS in a C# variable ...

Comment: The page that was already developed was using several printWindow.document.write statements to build a page for printing. So instead of printWindow.document.write('< bunch css styles >');  I was trying to at least make something more readable. printWindow.document.write('@myCSS');

Comment: In that case  `printWindow.document.write('@Html.Raw(myCSS)');` should do the work